# Hide row with specific cell value DataGridView C#

Tags: datagridview, hide, rows

I'm having trouble hiding rows with `0` value in `DataGridView`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.taggGrid.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value).Equals(0))
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The row I want to hide still shows.

Comment: Please post answer as answer and then accept it :)  It is OK to answer your own question if you find the solution later and no answers exist or none better exist.

Answer (score 6):

(Answered by the OP in edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> ANSWER: Solved it myself:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in taggGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "False")
            {
                dr.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```